# How send a DM in Instagram with React?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I want to add an Instagram button that allow a user to share a link directly inside a direct message: when they click the button, they will be redirected to their friend list and choose the receiver, then click the send button (the input field should include the URL).

I'm unable to find something like the WhatsApp API (like `https://whatsapp.com/send?text=message`) or Facebook [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog/).

I found [instagram-private-api](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api) but I'm looking to use a Facebook API or dialog for that instead.

Is there any useful link or suggestion for that?

Comment: As far as I know, they do not offer any such functionality.